# When a PDF-file created in IOS is e-mailed to a Windows recipient, will the metadata always be exactly the same?

Tags: email, metadata, ios

Specifically I'm interested in the fields "creator" and "producer".
I've made a small experiment mailing a file to and from a Mac, suggesting it will be changed in the Mac, but I've encountered a IT-forensic specialist who says that's impossible.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The act of emailing the file will not change any of the data in the file.

That does not mean that some program on your Mac or iOS device cannot change the file before it is sent or after it is received.

It largely depends on where the fields you are looking at are stored. If the fields are part of the filesystem that holds the file rather than the file data then that may not be transferred via email, but if the fields are stored within the file data itself then they will not be changed.

For example the filesystem may hold data indicating the user who created the file. As far as the receiving computer is concerned the file was "created" by the email program and that program was run as your local Mac user, not whoever created it on the iOS device.